# Is there an API for Java to calculate code churn?

Tags: svn, project-management, java

I'm looking for a Java Library similar to [nchurn](https://github.com/jondot/nchurn/tree/master/tools/NChurn) to be able to get the information about which files in a repository have been changed a lot... I need some information similar to the following so that I can perform calculations.

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
| lib/rubikon/application/instance_methods.rb | 48 |
| lib/rubikon/application.rb                  | 30 |
| test/test.rb                                | 30 |
| lib/rubikon/command.rb                      | 28 |
| lib/rubikon/parameter.rb                    | 17 |
| test/application_tests.rb                   | 14 |
| Rakefile                                    | 13 |
| lib/rubikon/application/dsl_methods.rb      | 12 |
```

Does anyone know of such API where I can get code churn information please? It has to be in Java though.

Thanks for your help

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54318/any-tools-to-get-code-churn-metrics-for-a-subversion-repository ?

Comment: Why do you need it? Use `nchurn` in your build as-is.

Comment: DMoses - I've tried some of the tools mentioned there but they dont produce what I need.

Comment: @AlexR - I am building a tool and I need the churn to be able to identify which files in a repository have been mostly changed.. I need a jar file for java... the libraries which I have found are dlls

Comment: Aw man.  I'd never heard of this tool before, got all excited to try it out, and it's Windows-only.  _Ew._

Comment: Read sources of [StatSVN](http://sourceforge.net/projects/statsvn/)?

Comment: yes i did.... it provides charts... i need some form of calculations that I can then use in my calculations... and I also need the differences of each and every file in the repository and not the differences as a whole

Answer (score 2):

For SVN, [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/index.html) offers a view of files with the most revisions. See [here](http://www.statsvn.org/statsvn/file_sizes.html#Files_With_Most_Revisions) for HTML output example. It's written in java, so if you need a java API, as opposed to just getting the information, you can probably dig into the implementation that produces that HTML and call the classes directly somehow. The source code is in the StatSVN sourceforge [repo](http://statsvn.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/statsvn/trunk/statsvn/).